# How is Rails.cache variable available across threads?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

If i write a value into say `Rails.cache.write('foo', :bar)` inside a rails controller action, how is this available inside a rails console context run at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since cache is simply a storage (of your choice), it does not matter, where you are accessing it from, controller, model, console - wherever the `Rails` is defined, `Rails.cache.fetch/read/write/etc` will work.

Comment: I am trying to understand how this is achieved. Cache stays stays only in the ROM right? I am missing something basic here and not able to get it.

Comment: @ZX12R no, it is not locked in ROM.